# Detect ISP (Network provider) name from Python program

Tags: python

I am executing automated tests using Python scirpts, these tests are executed on multiple networks. I needed to record the name of the ISP name active during the testing.

How to identify the name of ISP/Network provider name from a Python program?

Comment: Look for a whois and a geo-location library. I guess those will help you on that.

Comment: BTW, Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Those will help you getting better answers.